# Can not install self-signed certificate on Android Default Emulator or Genymotion

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, genymotion

Im having trouble for installing self-signed certificate for ssl on android emulator.
In **security** settings I selected the certificate to install

[image]

However, when I selected the **Trusted Credentials** -> **User**

There's nothing in there

[image]

Comment: I was successful by following the steps in this web page: https://kodmunki.wordpress.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Android can install self-signed CA although it refuses self-signed certificate.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61540/self-signed-certificate-install-claims-success-but-android-acts-as-if-cert-isn

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot add self-signed certificate to Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can if you install a self-signed ROOT cert:
[ssl app dev](https://medium.com/@noumaan/ssl-app-dev-a2923d5113c6)